# Slide Background Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

have 3 images using JavaScript am making them to slide from left to right for the body  background of html but the images are just appearing is there any thing i have to do so that they smoothly slide.

FYI: I have added a div to Preview.

Hear is the
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nkc3ebpy/#&togetherjs=38Bmm0beQ7)

```js
var bgArr = [
  "http://foxarc.com/en/cfxs/images/masks.jpg",
  "http://foxarc.com/en/cfxs/images/brushes.jpg",
  "http://foxarc.com/en/cfxs/images/text.jpg"
];
var i = 0;

// Start the slide show
setInterval(function() {
  $("#demo").css("background-image", "url(" + bgArr[i] + ")");
  (i < bgArr.length - 1) ? i++ : i = 0
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div
       id="demo" 
       style="text-align:center; 
          width:90%; 
          height:310px; 
          overflow:hidden; 
          border-style:dashed; 
          border-width:1px;">
    <p style="margin-top:83px;"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to implement slideshow transition effects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504007/how-to-implement-slideshow-transition-effects)

Comment: what do you mean "slide"? like a slider? As in one image shows then "slides" to the left/right?

Comment: @RobScott,@Mr. Polywhirl the backgroung image(s) of a body should slide from left to right

Comment: [`Basic Image Slider`](http://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/vGDHl)

Comment: @ozil i dont need a slider want entire body background to slide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution is to create 2 `div`s inside of `body`

```
<div class="background-1"></div>
<div class="background-2"></div>
```

and put them under it

```
body {
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.background-1, .background-2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then create a custom slider

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var bgArr = ["http://foxarc.com/en/cfxs/images/masks.jpg",
                 "http://foxarc.com/en/cfxs/images/brushes.jpg",
                 "http://foxarc.com/en/cfxs/images/text.jpg"]; 

    var i = 0;

    var $bg1 = $('.background-1').css('background-image', 'url('+bgArr[0]+')')
                                 .css('left', '0%');
    var $bg2 = $('.background-2').css('background-image', 'url('+bgArr[1]+')')
                                 .css('left', '-100%');

    var bgSlide = function($bg) {
        $bg.animate({ left: '+=100%' }, 600, function(){ 
            if(parseInt($bg.css('left')) > 0) {
                $bg.css('left', '-100%');
                (i < bgArr.length-1) ? i++ : i=0;
                $bg.css("background-image", "url("+bgArr[i]+")");
            }                           
        } );
    }

    setInterval(function() {                
        bgSlide($bg1);
        bgSlide($bg2);                          
    }, 2000);
});
```

Example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tptL43cL/1/)

Comment: superb was expecting the same :) but the edges are still visible in the left side cant it be hidden  before sliding

Comment: @ShaikAsif for `body` set `margin: 0` and probably `padding: 0` too. By the way I suggest using [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or something similar for your projects.

Comment: Well nice i vl have a quick question how to slide three images

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Nothing had some clarification got it But the problem is after all slides when it come to first the first image is stopping and again the slide starts can u help me on that

Comment: Yeah, there is a little mistake. The second image should be the next out of image array instead of being previous. Updated my post a little.

Answer (score 0):

See this example https://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/0Lr9uvt0/1/ **with animate()**

**without animate()** : https://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/0Lr9uvt0/2/

What is  [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

See this example https://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/0Lr9uvt0/5/  in this example i use jquery ui for left right effect

```
$('.test').css({
            'background-image': "url('" + bgArr[i] + "')"
        });
        (i < bgArr.length - 1) ? i++ : i = 0
}, 2000);
```

And apply css

```
.test{
    -webkit-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
     transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;

}
```

Comment: was gud but the images are not moving from left to right thery are just fading

Comment: @ShaikAsif see i updated my answer now apply your effect in css it will work

Comment: they are not moving from left to right :( they should slide

Comment: entire dive is moving cant the and that is toggling t hey should slide one by one as a background

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81969/discussion-between-keval-bhatt-and-shaik-asif).